Should Homomorphic Encryption Keys Be Generated by a Key Generation Server or the Data Owner?
I'm currently working on a project involving homomorphic encryption and I'm trying to determine the best practices for key generation. Specifically, I'm unsure whether the keys should be generated by a centralized key generation server or directly by the data owner.
What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach in terms of security, performance, and usability? Are there any industry standards or best practices that recommend one method over the other? Additionally, how does the choice affect the trust model and the overall architecture of the system?
Any insights or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

There is no best practice, there are good practices depending on your requirements. You did not mention why the data owner must trust the centralized key generation. FHE is meant to reduce the trust in servers so that one can outsource the computation. Now, you want to have centralized key gen?

@kelalaka Thank you for your response. You make an important point about the purpose of homomorphic encryption and reducing trust in centralized key gen. Given this context, it seems that the data owner should generate the encryption and decryption keys and share the evaluation key with the computing node. The server should just store the public key to guarantee the origin of the information.
